# How to populate a radio button group with mysql data?

Tags: php, html

I need to populate a radio group with the data saved on a mysql database using that very same radio group in a previous session. Now, normally I would just fetch the data into a variable .row and echo it under the value attribute but since the value att. for each radio button is set to the data I need to save if the button is selected I can't use it to show the fetched data form mysql.

How can I show the value previously saved on the database for the radio button group?

I've been looking for different solutions and everybody seems to answer that I should just fetch the date and echo it. Which confuses me because the value attribute is being used to depict what should be saved if the user select the button.

Let's use one of my groups. This question gets saved correctly on submit but I dont know how to show the saved value on refresh.

```
<div class="one">
<h1 class="text">Qual a cor dos seus olhos?</h1>
                          </div>
                          <p>
                                  <label>
                                    <input type="radio" class="option" name="ojos[]"  value="Avelã" id="ojos_0">
                                    Avelã</label>
                                  <br>
                                  <label>
                                    <input type="radio" class="option" name="ojos[]"  value="Castanho oscuro" id="ojos_1">
                                    Castanho oscuro</label>
                                  <br>
                                  <label>
                                    <input type="radio" class="option" name="ojos[]"  value="Azul" id="ojos_2">
                                    Azul</label>
                                  <br>
                                  <label>
                                    <input type="radio" class="option" name="ojos[]"  value="Azul esverdeado" id="ojos_3">
                                    Azul esverdado</label>
                                  <br>
                                  <label>
                                    <input type="radio" class="option" name="ojos[]"  value="Verde" id="ojos_4">
                                    Verde</label>
                                  <br>
                                  <label>
                                    <input type="radio" class="option" name="ojos[]"  value="Ambar" id="ojos_5">
                                    Ambar</label>
                                  <br>
                                  <label>
                                    <input type="radio" class="option" name="ojos[]"  value="Cinza" id="ojos_6">
                                    Cinza</label>
                                  <br>
                                  <label>
                                    <input type="radio" class="option" name="ojos[]"  value="Violeta" id="ojos_7">
                                    Violeta</label>
                                  <br>
                          </p>
```

as I told before, the entire form (which is close to 23 questions like the one posted before) saves perfectly fine. I just need to populate it with the previously saved data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a validation to the input with the value you are receiving from your database.

```
<label>
  <input 
    type="radio" 
    class="option" 
    name="ojos[]"  
    value="Azul" 
    id="ojos_2" 
    <?php $ojosval == 'Azul'? echo 'checked' : '' ?> 
/>Azul</label>
```

What I'm doing here is checking if the value you got from the database `$ojosval` is equal to the value of that input, if the validation is true, you will just add the `checked` property which will select the radio.

I haven't coded PHP for a while, but I think that should work.